# Detecting Calcified stones and cracks in tooth

Tags: teeth, hygiene

I had a dental problem when my first molar broke some months ago and after some decay and pain I am undergoing a dental treatment. The doctor was performing a root canal and kept on talking about calcified stones being formed and looking for a 'tak' sound inspite of having x-rays. Doctor did not point to the calcified stones earlier and suddenly came out with this new issue. In the mean time when looking for stones doctor actually managed to break my tooth and has blamed grinding and clenching for a crack that caused the tooth to break.

I am shocked that neither the calcified stone nor the crack showed up in x-ray and the preliminary examination. With current technology, can the cracks in tooth and calcified stones not be detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracks on your teeth are hard to detect if they are cracks on the mesial or distal surfaces (surface of the tooth closest to and farthest from the midline respectively) through x-rays. Please check [this link](http://www.dental.umaryland.edu/dentalstudent/download/Introduction_to_Dental_Terms_2.pdf) for illustrations and very good explanations from the University of Maryland dentistry department. The different methods on the detection of cracks as well as the uses of radiographic evidence can be found in [this link.](http://www.aae.org/uploadedfiles/publications_and_research/endodontics_colleagues_for_excellence_newsletter/ltfbonusmaterial_c.pdf)

Now pulp stones can be identified through x-rays unless they are too small or not too dense. There has been researches done specifically using radiographs for detection like ["A radiographic assessment of the prevalence of pulp stones in Australians"](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/11336590_A_radiographic_assessment_of_the_prevalence_of_pulp_stones_in_Australians). It could also be human error that your doctor was unable to detect it. A small explanation on pulp stones can be found [here](http://www.breadentistry.com/files/pdf/OPG_pul_sto.pdf).